# Can a dipole keep rotating with increasing angular velocity?

Tags: electric-fields, dipole

Let's say, we have a dipole and we know  if we keep it in uniform electric field it allines it self along the electric field direction.so can we some how make an arrangement to rotate it indefinitely with increasing angular  velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if we allow the system to be dynamic. This is more or less how electric motors work, except that for motors, the dipole is magnetic.

For the electric dipole, we could do it by, for example, turning the external field off as the dipole passes through its stable equilibrium, and on again as it passes through its unstable equilibrium (that is, off when the dipole is aligned with the field, and on again when it is antialigned with the field). In that case, the torque from the field is always contributing to the dipole's angular momentum, and never detracting from it.

Note though that if we want the dipole to undergo an indefinite angular acceleration, we'll have to keep putting work into the system, as we'd expect from energy conservation. A static field won't cut it -- the dipole would just oscillate back and forth around alignment with the field.